# Contact Form 7 - mail not sending on App Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, contact-form-7

I have installed latest version 4.8.1 of Contact Form 7 wordpress plug in.

Configured settings with authorised sender but when teting form mail doesnt not send.

Checked the App Engine request logs and found this:

```
Mail error: Input header 'X-WPCF7-Content-Type: text/plain' is not whitelisted for use with the Google App Engine Mail Service.
```

I'm not sure of what this error means and therefore how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Using standard wp_mail is never recommended.

I suggest using Wordpress Easy WP SMTP to set the email sender details.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/

Then you can tell Wordpress to send from a specific mailbox.
For example anything@[APP_NAME].appspotmail.com

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the mail tab option, you find out there is a 'To' input field in this field add you email address for e.g : abc@example.com

and in from field add your name short code for e.g :[your-name] [your-email]
same goes for subject : [your-subject]

add these configuration to your contact-form-7 it will help you out